# I need to groupby only by the month and day part of 'Date' and get the maximum and minimum of each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe. I have the data from 2005 to 2014. Here is the head() of my dataframe:

```
             ID       Date Element  Data_Value
2   USC00087020 2005-12-06    TMAX         272
5   USC00084095 2006-07-25    TMAX         328
6   USC00084095 2011-07-26    TMAX         333
7   USC00088841 2008-10-26    TMAX         294
12  USC00085667 2015-10-07    TMAX         300
14  USC00087760 2013-04-02    TMAX         322
15  USR0000FCHE 2010-05-26    TMAX         311
16  USC00088841 2007-12-27    TMAX         256
```

I need to groupby by month and day irrespective of the year. I used following code:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='M')).agg({'Data_Value':np.max})
```

and got the result like this:

```
            Data_Value
Date                  
2005-01-31         294
2005-02-28         300
2005-03-31         344
2005-04-30         322
2005-05-31         367
2005-06-30         383
2005-07-31         372
2005-08-31         361
```

But I need following format. So I can take the max and min of each month of all the years:

```
Date    Data_Value
Jan     217
Feb     240
Mar     228
Apr     190
May     250
```

How can I achieve it? Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert your Date columns back to date format by using `to_datetime`, then `groupby` with that columns only pick the month

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df.groupby(df.Date.dt.strftime('%B')).Data_Value.max()
Out[290]: 
Date
April       322
December    272
July        333
May         311
October     300
Name: Data_Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `strftime` seems more suitable for OP's desired output. I vote for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas.to_datetime`:

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month)['Data_Value'].max()

Date
4     322
5     311
7     333
10    300
12    272
```

Comment: That is really 1 sec :-)!!